# Checking next row in table is incremented by 1 minute in datetime column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to check alot of data in a Table to make sure my feed has not skipped anything.

Basically the table has the following columns

ID     Datetime      Price

The data in DateTime column is incremented by 1 minute in each successive row.  I need to check the next row of the current one to see if is 1 minute above the one being queries in that specific context.

The query will probably need some sort of loop, then grab a copy of the next row and compare it to the datetime row of the current to make sure it is incremented by 1 minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a test-table to match your description, and inserted 100 rows with 1 minute between each row like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test] ([Id] int IDENTITY(1,1), [Date] datetime, [Price] int);

WITH [Tally] AS (
  SELECT GETDATE() AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(minute, -1, [Date]) FROM [Tally] WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(minute, -99, GETDATE())
)
INSERT INTO [Test] ([Date], [Price])
    SELECT [Date], 123 AS [Price]
    FROM [Tally]
```

Then i deleted a record in the middle to simulate a missing minute:

```
DELETE FROM [Test]
WHERE Id = 50
```

Now we can use this query to find missing records:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    ,CASE WHEN b.[Id] IS NULL THEN 'Next record is Missing!' ELSE CAST(b.[Id] as varchar) END AS NextId
FROM
    [Test] AS a
    LEFT JOIN [Test] AS b ON a.[Date] = DATEADD(minute,1,b.[Date])
WHERE
    b.[Id] IS NULL
```

The resullt will look like this:

```
Id          Date                    Price       NextId
----------- ----------------------- ----------- ------------------------------
49          2013-05-11 22:42:56.440 123         Next record is Missing!
100         2013-05-11 21:51:56.440 123         Next record is Missing!

(2 row(s) affected)
```

The key solution to the problem is to join the table with itself, but use datediff to find the record that is supposed to be found on the next minute. The last record of the table will of course report that the next row is missing, since it hasn't been inserted yet.

Comment: This does locate the gaps in my data, however one small point is that it shows the row after the gap, so the 'Next record is missing' should be 'Last row was skipped' or something. This is probably because your Test table increments time from more recent at row 1 to more in the past in row 100, while my actual data has the earliest time at row 1.  Small point anyhow, this does help me see the gaps and functionally that is what I need to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing TheQ's sample data you can use

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', [Date]) - 
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS G
         FROM   Test)
SELECT MIN([Date]) AS StartIsland,
       MAX([Date]) AS EndIsland
FROM   T
GROUP  BY G
```

Comment: I tried this on my data, I am using SQL Server 2008 Express R2. I got:                                 Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Recursive common table expression 'Test' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Comment: +1 Nice solution with min. logical reads (the source table is read just once).

Comment: @magister - You would get that error if you renamed the CTE to `Test`. It has to be given a different name from the source table. In my answer the CTE is named `T` and the source table is `Test`. The code in my answer does *not* give that error. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6598e/1)